# How can I make a Button stay disable conected to Textblock in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBox` that i want it to control a `Button`.
that as long as nothing writen in the `TextBox` the `Button` will be dissabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this all in `XAML` using a `Style` `DataTrigger`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" />
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=myTextBlock}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Troggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use data binding and a converter

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToBoolConverter}}" />
```

and the converter looks like this:

```
 public class TextToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var text = value as string;

            if (text.Length > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

and this goes in your page:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:TextToBoolConverter x:Name="TextToBoolConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```